# SQL Server fetching data sequentially with unique value combination from table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

As part of my project I need to design catalog tree which require to fetch data from Sql database tables in specific format .Below are the tables with dummy data and expected result. It will be great help from you guys to find the solution.

**catalog_tree_mstr**  table

```
id  | catalog_code |    | attribute_id  | level
1     1                    1                 1
2     1                    2                 2
3     1                    3                 6
4     2                    3                 1
5     2                    1                 2
```

This table 'catalog_tree_mstr' contains the Attribute associated with catalog and attribute level( Attribute Order in which result will display).

Column 'attribute_id' is reference key to table 'attributes'.

**attributes**  table

```
id   |   attribute_systemname
1           attribute_01
2           attribute_02
3           attribute_03
```

This 'attributes' table having name of the attributes.

**dynamic_article_mstr**   table

```
id  |  article_id   |  attribute_01 |  attribute_02  |  attribute_03
1          1            performance      football        accessories
2          2            performance      football        apparel
3          3            performance      football        apparel
4          4            Performance      basketball      footwear
5          5            Performance      basketball      accessories
7          6            Originals        Football        Apparel
9          8            Originals        basketball      Apparel
10         9            Originals        basketball      accessories
11         10           Originals        basketball      Apparel
```

This 'dynamic_article_mstr' table having attributes name as columns.

I want to display every unique combination of attribute values as comma separated as shown below.

Input parameter is 'catalog _code' for table 'dynamic_article_mstr'.

**Below is required result for catalog_code = 1**

```
    1       performance,football,accessories
    2       performance,football,apparel
    3       Performance,basketball,footwear
    4       Performance,basketball,accessories
    5       Originals,Football,Apparel
    6       Originals,basketball,Apparel
    7       Originals,basketball,accessories
```

**Below is required result for catalog_code = 2**

```
    1   accessories,performance
    2   accessories,Originals
    3   apparel,performance
    4   apparel,Originals
    5   footwear,Performance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that this is not optimized but this query should meet your expectations:

```
DECLARE @CatalogCode INT = 2;

DECLARE @tmp TABLE (id INT, article_id INT, att1 NVARCHAR(30), att2 NVARCHAR(30), att3 NVARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @tmp ( id, article_id, att1, att2, att3 )
SELECT  x.id ,
        x.article_id ,
        x.attribute_01 ,
        x.attribute_02 ,
        x.attribute_03
FROM    ( SELECT    dam.id ,
                    dam.article_id ,
                    CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                       FROM     dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm
                                       WHERE    ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode
                                               AND ctm.attribute_id = 1 )
                         THEN dam.attribute_01
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS attribute_01 ,
                    CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                       FROM     dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm
                                       WHERE    ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode
                                                AND ctm.attribute_id = 2 )
                         THEN dam.attribute_02
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS attribute_02 ,
                    CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                       FROM     dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm
                                       WHERE    ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode
                                                AND ctm.attribute_id = 3 )
                         THEN dam.attribute_03
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS attribute_03
          FROM      dbo.dynamic_article_mstr dam
        ) x;

SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT x.att1 + ',' AS [text()]
FROM
(
    SELECT  t.id ,
            t.article_id ,
            t.att1 ,
            (SELECT ctm.level FROM dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm WHERE ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode AND ctm.attribute_id = 1) AS lvl
    FROM @tmp t
    WHERE t.att1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.id ,
            t.article_id ,
            t.att2 ,
            (SELECT ctm.level FROM dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm WHERE ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode AND ctm.attribute_id = 2)
    FROM @tmp t
    WHERE t.att2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.id ,
            t.article_id ,
            t.att3 ,
            (SELECT ctm.level FROM dbo.catalog_tree_mstr ctm WHERE ctm.catalog_code = @CatalogCode AND ctm.attribute_id = 3)
    FROM @tmp t
    WHERE t.att3 IS NOT NULL ) x
    WHERE dam.article_id = x.article_id
    ORDER BY x.lvl ASC
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS att
FROM    dbo.dynamic_article_mstr dam
```

Comment: Dear Rafal thanks for your solution. I need some more help from you, Here Attributes are not fixed in 'dynamic_article_mstr' table, attributes are decided at run-time while building the catalog so i am not able to hard code the @tmp temp table with fixed column. And attribute Ids also not fixed it should be dynamically coming from 'catalog_tree_mstr' table.